# Processamento de texto

Tags: python

Tenho o seguinte cenário: tenho uma variável com um texto dentro. Eu separo esse texto por palavras dentro de um *array*, com isso eu preciso validar quantas vezes cada palavra aparece no texto. Eu consegui fazer, mas tem um outro detalhe, eu preciso correr a lista toda sem passar por uma palavra que já peguei a contagem.

Ex: "Num ninho de mafagafos há sete mafagafinhos. Quando a mafagafa gafa, gafam os sete mafagafinhos."

Neste caso eu não consigo passar o código sem repetir o "mafagafinhos". O que eu faço?

Comment: Você pode postar o trecho de seu código que faz esta contagem de palavras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um exemplo de contador de palavras poderia ser feito da seguinte maneira:

```
import sys
text = "Num ninho de mafagafos há sete mafagafinhos. Quando a mafagafa gafa, gafam os sete mafagafinhos."
wordcount={}
for word in text.split():
    if word not in wordcount:
        wordcount[word] = 1
    else:
        wordcount[word] += 1
for key in wordcount.keys():
    print("%s %s " %(key , wordcount[key]))
```

Comment: Veja [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211850/processamento-de-texto#comment433217_211850).

Comment: Didaticamente a resposta está ok para se perceber a lógica, mas convém sublinhar que há maneiras melhores melhores para fazer isso. Exemplo de três maneiras diferentes mas mais 'pythonicas': http://ideone.com/A2zCH9